# ReactJS - I can't pass prop trought Route for a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this Component that passes a prop for a Child Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'    
import PortfolioPage from './PortfolioPage'  

class PortfolioMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // here is the prop to be passed for a child component
    this.state = {       
      interiorsUrl: "http://localhost:3001/interiors"
    }
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="wrapper-portfolio">
              // here is the line to pass the prop
              <Route exact path='/portfolio/interiores' render={() => <PortfolioPage interiorsUrl={this.state.interiorsUrl}/>} />
            <nav>
              <ul>   
                <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to="/portfolio/interiores">• interiores</NavLink></li>                  
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default PortfolioMenu
```

Here is the Child Component who receives the props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';


const URL = this.props.interiorsUrl;


class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: []
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL)

//...rest of the code omitted
```

In the Component above, there is an error's message on the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'interiorsUrl' of undefined

It is pointed to this code line:

```
 const URL = this.props.interiorsUrl;
```

What did I wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call this.props.interiorsUrl from inside your component.

So anywhere instead the { } after class

eg:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.props.interiorsUrl)
}
```

Comment: Like this?

 componentDidMount() {
    const URL = this.props.interiorsUrl;
    axios.get(URL)

Comment: I noticed when I did this change the component is loading the images slower. Does exist another better place to insert this line?

Comment: there shouldn't be much difference at all (not noticeable anyway) but you could try and do this in your constructor. That will fire before componentDidMount but it is not recommended to do that there - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: @claudiobitar if you are using axios to load just images with a GET request it should be quicker to just set that to the src attribute of an <img /> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: []
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { interiorsUrl } = this.props;
    axios.get(interiorsUrl)
      .then(response => this.setState({ result: response.data }))
      .catch(e => console.error(e));

  }
  //...rest of the code omitted
```